# Clearing left, but only so far

Tags: html, css

I have a set of divs and one image that I am trying to format to look like :

[image: Proper Flow]

At first attempt it is pretty easy, I float image and name left, float the suffix right and clear:right; the title.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/200x150?text=var+w%26h' class='image' />
    <div class='name'></div>
    <div class='suffix'></div>
    <div class='title'></div>
    <div class='notes'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:5px;
    width:500px;
}
.image{
    float:left;
    margin:0 5px 5px 0;
}
.name{
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
}
.suffix{
    border:1px solid blue;
    float:right;
}
.title{
    border:1px solid green;
    clear:right;
}
```

However, all of my fields are variable, and can be different sizes, multiple lines etc.  So, clearing right on the title may be clearing a one (or even zero) line suffix, but name could be 3 lines:

[image: Improper Flow]

I can use an inner wrapper with `overflow:hidden;` or `overflow:auto;` on everything but the picture, and then `clear:both;` the title, but then I lose the notes wrapping around the image.

[image]

How can I maintain proper flow on all parts?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/j6v1kmdp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put `div.notes` into `div.inner_wrapper`:

```css
.wrapper {
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:5px;
    width:500px;
}
.inner_wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
}
.image{
    float:left;
    margin:0 5px 5px 0;
}
.name{
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
}
.suffix{
    border:1px solid blue;
    float:right;
}
.title{
    border:1px solid green;
    clear:right;
}
.inner_wrapper .title{
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/100x100?text=var+w%26h' class='image' />
    <div class='inner_wrapper'>
        <div class='name'>name<br />is<br />multiline</div>
        <div class='suffix'>suffix</div>
        <div class='title'>title</div>
    </div>
        <div class='notes'>notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes notes</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is the image resized?

Comment: @A.Abramov because it is its own size, see the [link](https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=11&txt=var+w%26h&w=100&h=100&txttrack=0)

Comment: @A.Abramov It's the same size as OP's last example.

Answer (score 0):

There are other tools that could help you here, such as flex box or absolute positioning. I think you can also achieve what you want with floats, but unless the semantic order of elements is critical, I would move `suffix` inside `name`, before the actual name in the markup and use the following style:

```
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 500px;
}

.wrapper .image {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.wrapper .suffix {
    float: right;
}

.wrapper .title {
    clear: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/helmers/07hh2ft1/1/

Comment: This works great if name is multiline, but does not solve the problem if name is single line and suffix is multiline